# List<String> addAll() method not adding

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make changes to the data source directly and notify the adapter of any changes. But addAll() does not update my list. It seems everything is OK in my code, but not during run. Please help me to correct the code. Thank You in Advance.

```
    List<String> pgs = myClass.getPgs();
    List<String> tmppgs = pgs;

    /*
    .
     lots of code for string processing which results in >> String content for each i
    .
     */

    for (int i = 0; i < tmppgs.size(); i++) {
    tmppgs.set(i, content);
    }

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(tmppgs.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Toast shows desired result which is OK.

    pgs.clear();
    pgs.addAll(tmppgs);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(pgs.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Unexpectedly shows zero

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: `tmppgs == pgs`. You're clearing both.

Comment: No, first toast shows correct result. The problem begins from pgs.clear().

Comment: Just a guess, Have you tried List<String> tmppgs = new ArrayList<String>(pgs); ?

Answer (score 1):

`pgs` and `temppgs` are the same `ArrayList` object:

```
List<String> tmppgs = pgs;
```

Hence, when you call `pgs.clear()`, you are emptying that one list. `pgs.addAll(tmppgs)` will have no effect, because you are attempting to add the contents of an empty list to itself.

It is unclear why you are doing the `clear()` and `addAll()` in the first place. If your objective is to wind up with the list modified via the `set()` calls... you are already modifying that list via the `set()` calls. Just comment out the `clear()` and `addAll()` lines (and, eventually, get rid of `tmppgs`, since you no longer need it).

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for the answer. As I said, I need to act directly on the existing reference because reinitializing the list will not affect the adapter, since it has a memory reference to the old list.

Comment: @ab0001368: Hence, do what I wrote in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I have directly modified pgs instead of tmppgs which solved returning zero size of list. But recyclerview behaves   Unexpectedly in updating items. Size of list is 3 (recyclerview shows 3 webviews). first and second items are not updated. but  3 updated items (3 texts) are shown in third webview!!!

Comment: @ab0001368: That sounds like a bug in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` or your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, wherever you are updating the items.

Comment: because of this problem, I used List<String> tmppgs and before updating pgs, i cleared pgs which i faced the problem of zero size of pgs. is there any way for correction of pgs.addAll(tmppgs) which return correct size?

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
List<String> tmppgs = pgs;
```

to

```
List<String> tmppgs = myClass.getPgs();;
```

shall work for you.